# Export and edit XML metadata in Diagrams.net?

Tags: microsoft-excel, xml, diagrams, uml

I have a large UML class diagram which I can open in diagrams.net. I also have an Excel file containing metadata for each of those classes. I would like to add the metadata from the Excel file to the diagram. I'm aware that you can add metadata to an individual class using the Ctrl+M keyboard shortcut, but doing this for each individual class is going to take ages.

I'm thinking the best option might be to export the UML diagram as an XML file, combine this with the metadata, and then import the combined XML file back into diagrams.net. - Does anyone have any suggestions about the best way of doing this? (I'm guessing that I can't use Excel to modify the XML file?)